# Swiftui how to catch taps on menu item

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to catch the tap on an item in a menu, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried something like this:

```
Menu("Tap me") {
    ForEach (references, id: \.self) { ref in
            Link(ref.name, destination: URL(string: ref.url))
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                    onLinkTapped()
                })
                .onTapGesture{
                    onLinkTapped()
                }
        }
}
```

but I never get to the `onLinkTapped()`. If it's not inside a `Menu`, then it works, but not inside the menu. How to catch the tap gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Button inside Menu:

```
Menu("Tap me") {
    ForEach (references, id: \.self) { ref in
        Button {
            onLinkTapped()
        } label: {
           Link(ref.name, destination: URL(string: ref.url))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. I'll need to manually open the URL with UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) though, so I guess that I can just use a text as the label.